# Appending new Immutable Map value to Immutable List

Tags: javascript, list, immutable.js, immutablelist

I have below a piece of code wherein I need to push a new Immutable Map value to an Immutable List on each forEach iteration. The flow goes into **if** condition as expected, but nothing is being pushed to the listOfFiles List. The console at the end of the forEach print list as List[0].

Any hint, on what should be corrected over here so it works fine?

Code

```
const formatListOfFilesObjectForAPI = (selectedListOfFileIds, allFilesData) => {

  const listOfFiles = new Immutable.List();
  selectedListOfFileIds.forEach(fileId => {
    const fileObject = allFilesData.getIn([fileId, 'result']);
    if(fileObject && fileObject.size > 0) {
      if(fileObject.get('provider') === 'intranet') {
        listOfFiles.push(new Immutable.Map({
          file_id: fileObject.get('fileId'),
          provider: fileObject.get('provider')
        }));
      } else {
        listOfFiles.push(new Immutable.Map({
          file_id: fileObject.get('fileId'),
          provider: fileObject.get('provider'),
          name: fileObject.get('basename'),
          type: fileObject.get('extension'),
          size: fileObject.get('size'),
          version: fileObject.get('version'),
        }));
      }
    } else {
      listOfFiles.push(new Immutable.Map({
        file_id: fileId,
        provider: 'intranet'
      }));
    }
  });

  console.log('listOfFiles', listOfFiles);

  return listOfFiles;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mutate an immutable list, so it's normal it doesn't change.

If you check the [Immutable documentation](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.0.0-rc.14/List/#push()) for e.g. `push()`, you'll see that it **returns a new list** with the result. Therefore in your example, you need to replace every `listOfFiles.push` with `listOfFiles = listOfFiles.push`.

Alternatively, use a regular array you can simply `push()` to and convert it to an immutable list at the end.